# SQL/PHP - Count results and show them according to HAVING clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

I have this query:

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT country_code,country_name FROM users WHERE country_code!='NA' AND country_name!='NA'");
$stmt->execute();
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

Which distinctly select some information from my database.

I then later loop the data in a foreach loop:

```
foreach ($rows as $row){
 //Do something
}
```

Although, I wish to be able to only use the result/data, **if** the there is more than 5 results in the original query.

**Example**:

If `country_code` and `country_name` with values `CA` and `canada` is present more than 5 times.

Comment: Curious are you asking if you want the data if specific values are found more then five times or if you want the data if the overall returned amount is more then 5?

Comment: The specific values.

Comment: you have mention group by and having. could you do something like this `select country_code, country_name from user group by country_code having count(country_code) >=5` http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ceedf/1/0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use group by and having to get the specific result. You could use count() function to count the number of row group by the specific column. You also could add expression as well if you only want country_code='CA' as the example below.

```
select country_code, country_name from user 
group by country_code 
having country_code='CA' and count(country_code) >=5
```

here is the example http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b62530/1

Comment: What about the distinct?

Comment: group by giving you distinct in a way. With distinct you need to count the row after the query. With group by, it group the same country_code to return only 1 row of that country code. So, it's a distinct country_code in a way. Unless there are other columns that you need apart from country_code. Then, the query will be different.